# If $f$ continuous in $[-1,1]$ Then $g(x)= \int_{-x}^x \! \, f(t)dt$ derivative in $[-1,1]$ and $g'(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

I have this problem its a proof/disproof problem.

For some reason I get wrong answer.

If $f$ continuous in $[-1,1]$ Then $g(x)= \int_{-x}^x \! \, f(t)dt$ derivative in $[-1,1]$ and $g'(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$

What I did:

Using the fundamental theorem since $f$ continuous $[-1,1]$ we can conclude that $f$ derivative in $[-1,1]$ and for all $x \in [-1,1]$ :
$$f(x)=F'(x)$$

Since $f$ continuous in $[-1,1]$ is also integrability, so using the fundamental forumula :

$$\int_{-x}^x \! \, f(t)dt=F(x)-F(-x) \implies g(x)= \int_{-x}^x \! \, f(t)dt=F(x)-F(-x)$$

So :

$$g(x)=F(x)-F(-x) \implies g'(x)=F'(x)-F'(-x) = f(x)-f(-x) \neq f(x)+f(-x)$$

So the statement is false, but for some reason in the answers I see that the answer is true, and I don't find any mistake I done.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as MPW said but I will post a separate answer since I cannot comment.

$g(x)=F(x)-F(-x)$

Differentiate that with respect to $x$.

Use the chain rule for $F(-x)$ and you'd get:

$(F(-x))'=F'(-x)*(-x)'=F'(-x)*(-1)=-F'(-x)$

Finally, we'd get: $g'(x)=F'(x)-(-F'(-x))=F'(x)+F'(-x)=f'(x)+f'(-x)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm familar with the chain law, but I don't understand why I should use it with $F'(-x)$ can you explain?

Comment: You're not using it with $F'(-x)$ per se, you actually use it with both $F(x)$ and $F(-x)$. You're differentiating with respect to $x$ not with respect to $-x$ so $F(x)$ will just yield $F'(x)$ since the variable in $F$ is $x$ while using the chain rule is needed in $F(-x)$ since the variable of the function $F$ is not $x$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you took the derivative of the integral incorrectly. You didn't use the chain rule properly for the lower limit in the integral, so you are missing a factor of $-1$ for that term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't see where I should factor $-1$, since $$(F(x)-F(-x))'=F'(x)-F'(-x)=f(x)-f(-x)$$ Can you explain?

Comment: The chain rule tells us that $$[F(-x)]' = F'(-x)\cdot (-x)' = F'(-x)\cdot(-1)=-F'(-x)$$ If that's confusing, just think of it as $F(G(x))$ where $G(x) = -x$. Then $$[F(G(x))]' = F'(G(x))\cdot G'(x)$$ But $G(x) = -x$, so $G'(x) = -1$ and this becomes $$[F(-x)]' = -F'(-x)$$

Answer (score 1):

You're *almost* there! Remember the chain rule:
$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f(g(x))] = f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)\text{.}$$
Thus,
$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F(-x)] = ?\text{.}$$